# Play a vimeo video forwards or backwards like in the example provided

Tags: controls, scrollbar, vimeo

This might be a challenge, but is it possible to make something like this:

https://codepen.io/ollieRogers/pen/lfeLc/

HTML:

```html
#set-height
p#time
video(id="v0",  tabindex="0", autobuffer preload)
    <source type="video/webm; codecs=&quot;vp8, vorbis&quot;" src="https://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.webm"></source>
    <source type="video/ogg; codecs=&quot;theora, vorbis&quot;" src="https://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.ogv"></source>
    <source type="video/mp4; codecs=&quot;avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2&quot;" src="https://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.mp4"></source>
    p Sorry, your browser does not support the &lt;video&gt; element.
```

JS:

```js
var frameNumber = 0, // start video at frame 0
    // lower numbers = faster playback
    playbackConst = 500, 
    // get page height from video duration
    setHeight = document.getElementById("set-height"), 
    // select video element         
    vid = document.getElementById('v0'); 
    // var vid = $('#v0')[0]; // jquery option

// dynamically set the page height according to video length
vid.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  setHeight.style.height = Math.floor(vid.duration) * playbackConst + "px";
});


// Use requestAnimationFrame for smooth playback
function scrollPlay(){  
  var frameNumber  = window.pageYOffset/playbackConst;
  vid.currentTime  = frameNumber;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);
```

CSS:

```css
#set-height  
  display block
#v0
  position fixed 
  top 0  
  left 0  
  width 100%

p font-family helvetica 
  font-size 24px
```

With a Vimeo video? So that you can control/play the Vimeo video with your scrollbar? Scrolling down is playing video forward, scrolling up is playing video backwards. Does anybody know this?

Comment: You might find the [Vimeo API Player SDK](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk) helpful in adapting your code. Specifically, see [Set the playback position of a video](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/reference#set-the-playback-position-of-a-video).

Comment: Hi Showdev, Can you help with that? I can't write my own codes...